# rails search for items with similar associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty standard many-to-many relationship. Items have many tags and vice versa, through an associations table. What I want to do is implement a search engine where the user searches for a particular item, and items with a similar array of tags(not exactly the same, it would be very rare for two items to have the exact same tags) would be returned, ordered from most similar to least similar. And there would have to be a cutoff point, a minimum degree of similarity an item would require to be returned.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the Levenshtein function (normally for comparing strings) to fit to your problem. Just one possible idea on the fast...

Comment: hmm. the problem with that is, since it's based on the number of edits required, then any two items with a substantial difference in the number of associations would by proxy not be considered similar.

Comment: i guess it's my best bet though. there is a levenshtein gem, i'll try it out.